# RESTful Web Services : How to simply post a paragraph entity

Tags: 8

I have simply activated the default paragraph ressource with core (8.8.3) module : 
[image: Basic config]

I would like to post a paragraph but even just with the "type" field, I got 403 error in response ! I have nearly the same request that works fine for node...

```
        var newReleve = {

          type: [{
            target_id: 'releve_de_chantier'
          }],
          parent_id: [{
            value: this.nid,
          }],
          parent_type: [{
            value: 'projet',
          }],
          // field_type_de_releve_de_chantier: [
          //   {
          //     value: this.typeReleve
          //   }
          // ],

        };

        if(this.pid) {
          newReleve.id = [{
            value: this.pid
          }]
        }


        fetch('/entity/paragraph'+(this.pid ? '/'+this.pid : '')+'?_format=json', {
          method: this.pid ? 'PATCH' : 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'X-CSRF-Token': csrfToken
          },
          body: JSON.stringify(newReleve)})
          .then(response => {
            if(response.ok){
              return response.json();
            } else {
              console.log(response);
              throw('Error posting datas ! Details below \n ' + response.status + ' : ' + response.statusText);
            }
          })
          .then(para => {
            // console.log(para);
            this.pid = para.id[0].value;
            console.log(this.pid);

          })
          .catch( error => {
            alert('Enregistrement du relevé non effectué : erreur interne du programme ! Détail de l\'erreur : \n ' + (error.message ? error.message : error) );
            console.error(error);
          });
```

Any idea ?

thanks

Comment: GET and DELETE work fine

Comment: And I'm testing with admin account...

Comment: And when POSTing, I only get the return :

Comment: {
    "message": ""
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, seems it comes from Paragraph module, file *ParagraphAccessControlHandler.php* function *checkCreateAccess* :

```
  protected function checkCreateAccess(AccountInterface $account, array $context, $entity_bundle = NULL) {
// Allow paragraph entities to be created in the context of entity forms.
if (\Drupal::requestStack()->getCurrentRequest()->getRequestFormat() === 'html') {
  return AccessResult::allowed()->addCacheContexts(['request_format']);
}
return AccessResult::neutral()->addCacheContexts(['request_format']);
```

}

Code goes in the second return as request format is not html but json. If I force the return to be AccessResult::allowed(), the paragraph is created. Why this restriction to forms ? How to overwrite this without patching ?